# Variety having infinite and perfect $\pi_1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

> **Question.** Does there exist a smooth complex projective variety with infinite and perfect fundamental group?

A group $G$ is perfect if its Abelianisation $G/[G,\, G]$ is the trivial group.

Comment: There's an extensive theory of Kähler groups, i.e. groups that can occur as the fundamental group of a compact Kähler manifold (which includes all smooth complex projective varieties). Searching for "Kähler groups" will find many papers.  I don't remember ever seeing anything about infinite perfect groups, but I am certainly not an expert in this area.

Comment: Thompson groups $T$ and $V$ don't work https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506254

Comment: Can $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for $n\geq 3$ occur?

Comment: @lacon $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ won't occur by work of Simpson [Higgs Bundles and local systems].

Comment: There are many infinite perfect 3-manifold groups but these don't occur. See work of Friedl, Kotschick, Suciu...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest example I know of such a group is given by the presentation
$$
\langle a, b, c| a^2, b^3, c^7, abc\rangle.
$$
This group $G$ is obviously perfect and (less obviously) is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a smooth complex-projective variety. The reason for the latter is that $G$ acts holomorphically, properly and cocompactly on the unit disk and contains a finite index torsion-free subgroup.

With this in mind, one uses the following lemma a form of which one can find in the book "Kahler groups":

**Lemma.** Suppose that $G$ is a group containing a torsion-free normal subgroup $H$ of finite index. Suppose that $G$ is acting holomorphically, properly on a simply-connected complex manifold $X$ such that $X/H$ is biholomorphic to a smooth complex-projective variety. Then $G$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of a smooth complex projective variety.

**Proof.** There exists a *simply-connected* projective variety $Z$ with a free holomorphic action of $G/H$. Now, form the fiber product
$$
Y=(X\times Z)/G
$$
where the action of $G$ on $X$ is as above and $G$ acts on $Z$ via the action of $G/H$. Then $\pi_1(Y)\cong G$ and $Y$ is biholomorphic to a smooth projective variety, since it is the quotient of the projective variety $W=(X/H) \times Z$ by a free holomorphic action of a finite group, namely $G/H$.

Comment: Looks good! (For those who don't see the last part of the argument. If $G$ is the above group and $H\subset G$ a finite index normal subgroup, we can choose a smooth projective  var. $Y$ with $\pi_1(Y)=G/H$. Then $X=(D\times Y)/G$ is a smooth projective variety with fund gp $G$.)

Comment: In my previous comment (which I can longer edit) $H$ was meant to be normal and torsion free. Also $Y$ exists by Serre.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth saying that explicitly that this is the "(2,3,7)-triangle group". It's a famous group! Do I understand correctly that your answer works for any hyperbolic triangle group? (Which will of course be perfect if $gcd(p,q,r)=1$.)

Comment: @HJRW: Yes, of course. I chose the parameters 2, 3, 7 since these are the smallest numbers (and the group is indeed famous). Although, I am not sure "triangle group" is the right name in this situation (usually, [triangle groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group) are required to be Coxeter groups). "Von Dyck group" is the standard terminology.

Comment: In your proof, you probably want to assume that $Z$ is simply-connected.

Comment: @AndyPutman: Yes, I forgot to say this.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I think more often than note people mean exactly this group. Indeed, to quote wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(2,3,7)_triangle_group), 'the "(2,3,7) triangle group" most often refers, not to the full triangle group $\Delta(2,3,7)$ ... but rather to the ordinary triangle group $D(2,3,7)$ of orientation-preserving maps (the rotation group), which is index 2.'

Comment: By the way, I once wrote a paper about (generalisations of) triangle groups with Jason Manning and Alex Lubotzky. I suggested we use the term "Von Dyck group", and Lubotzky told me that, in all his decades in group theory, he had never heard the term before. So I don't think it's really "standard" these days (though I grant that wikipedia says it is). We went with the term "ordinary triangle group", and usually omitted the word "ordinary".

Answer (score 6):

A number of such examples are known. For example, if $X$ is a  [fake projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane), then its fundamental group would be perfect and infinite (it's a lattice in $PU(2,1)$).

**Postscript**
As abx points out, these fundamental groups  have nontrivial finite abelianized fundamental groups, so they don't quite work. However, Moishe Kohan's answer gives a very simple example.

Comment: I don't think that the group is perfect. Its abelianization is $H_1(X,\Bbb{Z})$, which is never zero according to Prasad-Yeung (see e.g. [this paper](https://hkumath.hku.hk/~imr/IMRPreprintSeries/2008/IMR2008-19.pdf), 7.3, Corollary 1.

Comment: @abx OK, thanks. I'll edit when I get a chance, and include some bonafide examples.

Comment: Are there infinite simple Kähler groups?

Comment: @lacon: Nobody knows.

Comment: The issue with such lattices (as well as lattices in higher-dimensional Lie groups)  is that most known theorems guarantee vanishing of the 1st Betti numbers, but allow for finite nontrivial abelianization.